# Re-building a cross-validated SVM

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, svm, kernel-trick

Suppose we are cross-validating parameters of a Gaussian (radial) SVM on $k$ training observations. The parameters are the cost parameter $C$, and the deviation parameter $\gamma$.

Then, $4k$ more training observations arrive. If we train the SVM on the whole training set with the previously validated values $C,\gamma$ this will not be a good practice for obvious reasons. However, if we cross validate $C,\gamma$ on the training set on $5k$ observations, this will be too expensive.

Is there any way in between these two extreme practices, e.g., using directly parameters that are cross validated on the first $k$ observations versus cross-validating the whole $5k$ observations training set?

I would say, since we now have a lot more observations than before, we can instead assume the new $4k$ observations are the validation set. However, I am looking for an  answer which is directly from the SVM practice. Maybe there is a clever way.

Comment: Without having read the papers @usεr11852 linked (and fully expecting that this will be part of what they do): with more training data at hand now, you can considerably restrict the cost; gamma search space for the new data set since you expect the optimal solution to be of same or higher complexity - you'll probably not want to evaluate lower complexity models. Unfortunately, the high complexity ones are the computationally costly ones... (This assumes that you do not have systematic changes, i.e. drift in your data generation process)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Thanks for your comment. What do you mean by 'of higher complexity'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can treat this as an instance of [online (or incremental) machine learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_machine_learning). That is, given this new data use assume that the training data arrives in a continuous manner and we need to tune our hyper-parameters on the fly. In a way, we are doing a "warm start" in our problem.

There are quite a few papers on the matter particular for SVM:

- [Fast kernel classifiers with online and active learning](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/bordes05a/bordes05a.pdf) (2005) by Bordes et al.
- [Incremental Support Vector Learning: Analysis, Implementation and Applications](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/laskov06a/laskov06a.pdf) (2006) by Laskov et al.
- [Online SVM learning: from classification to data description and back](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1318049) (2003) by Tax & Laskov.

Please note that this is definitely not confined to SVM. Most algorithms that are trained in an iterative manner have been presented within an online/incremental learning framework.

Comment: thanks so much! So can we say that maybe we can first validate the trained parameters on the new $4k$ set. If we see that the error is still low, then the two datasets are alike. However, if the error is different, and we expect more and more data set coming in, then we should do incremental learning? I thought incremental learning is usually for the models where hyperparameters are fixed (e.g., in SVM, fix support vectors throw the rest away, bring the new data, and go on).

Comment: @independentvariable: hyperparameters are not really all that different from other parameters. The main difference is that they are parameters the developer of the algorithm couldn't left for you to fix, because they did not have an automated and generally applicable way to fix them.

Comment: @independentvariable I am happy I could help. We can definitely try what you said but realistically, with more data, we will like to get potentially a more generalisable and/or robust model. As cbeleites said, hyperparameters are not necessarily fixed.

Comment: @usεr11852 thanks for your reply. I had a quick look at the papers, and I think they fix the Kernel a-priori. Do you think it is easy to also train the hyperparamters  on the fly?

Comment: @usεr11852 I guess this is also the original paper, again we can see in the numerical experiments that the kernel's hyperparameters are fixed and the whole re-training is being done for the decision boundary(unfortunately...)
https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1814-incremental-and-decremental-support-vector-machine-learning.pdf

Comment: However, this one addresses also updating the hyper parameters:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1223991?casa_token=VP5wIEzEyK8AAAAA:Go-kxZKt3cQBvSL7ejAOxfd1i1xaCjJLGINetvwrjPBkm-D9sjnBujjCUeZajDvDEJht__dVScE

Comment: Cool. Yes, I have seen this latest paper (+1). Based on the question's text ($C$ and $\gamma$) I thought you had a fixed kernel type too. Clearly not all hyper-parameters are equally easy to retrain, if we cannot assume some kind of "path" (e.g. ala [Hastie et al. (2004)](http://www.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~jizhu/pubs/Hastie-JMLR04.pdf) we do not have any significant advantage when retraining.

Comment: Amazing discussion, thanks!